# How to deal with enemies with no weaknesses?

Tags: persona-5

In my infiltration of a palace I started to notice a bit of a trend with enemies I am fighting. More and more the enemies are either having hard to use weaknesses or the even worse case **no weaknesses at all**. I have ran into an extremely difficult set of enemies in a palace that consists of one or two enemies that are resistant to all physical attacks, and have no magical weaknesses at all. These enemies are nearly always backed up with healer enemies, which honestly don't pose too much of a threat but here is my problem.

How can I deal with these types of enemies with no weaknesses without having my party getting slaughtered while these enemies run rampant unable to be knocked down by anything besides a lucky critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that "lucky critical" is the only way to down an enemy with no weaknesses.

There are a few ways to improve your odds of getting a critical, however.

**Rebellion** and **Revolution** raise characters' critical hit rate. Rebellion affects a single target, while Revolution affects *all* allies **and** enemies. **Apt Pupil** is a passive skill that raises the user's critical rate and works wonders in conjunction with the following three skills.

**Lucky Punch** and **Miracle Punch** are both physical moves that have increased critical rates. Additionally, **One-Shot Kill** is a Gun skill with a high critical rate.

On top of that, there are some items you can equip in order to buff the chance to get a critical hit, too.

Another method is to rely on status ailments. All status ailments will help you take out enemies. For instance, Brainwash (previously called Charm) will cause enemies to either be "addled" during their turn (and do nothing) or attack their allies. Dizzy will lower their accuracy significantly. Despair will probably be the most reliable as it causes certain death, but it will take 3 turns to cause the enemy to die.

If you don't want to rely entirely on chance or status ailments, another good strategy that I've found is to debuff the problem enemy while also buffing your party to prevent them from dishing out too much damage while you whittle away their health the old-fashioned way.

Comment: I can't remember if I saw correctly with skills but I could have sworn there are a few skills that you can get that actually make enemies weak to certain elements.

Comment: @Ramirez I'm looking at the list of skills, but the closest I can find to that effect is to remove immunities/resistances. Let me keep looking for ones that add weaknesses.

Comment: I'm sure I might have just been seeing things but I think I remember a skill you could cast that would make an enemy's ice resistance weak. Might have just been seeing things though.

Comment: @Ramirez could you have been looking at the Break skills?

Comment: Those actually might have been them, I just looked at the Persona 5 skills and I am pretty sure those are what I actually saw.

Comment: @Ramirez ah okay then, yeah those just remove resistances, unfortunately. I was actually going to make a comment about Anubis in response to one of your other comments on a different question, but then you asked this so... just wait til you start seeing a bunch of Anubis :-)